# Not able to understand the implementation of the os module in cpython

Tags: python, module, cpython

So I wanted to check out some implementations of standard libraries. I started with the os library with the code being [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/os.py) on github.

I took one method for example `os.listdir()` and I have absolutely no idea how it is implemented even after looking at the code ( pardon this noob ). I have following questions:

- `os.__all__` do not list this method but I think it is definitely a method as `print(type(os.listdir))` listed `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>` and I searched on google to find all the builtin functions which I found on [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) doc page and this is not one of them.
- There is not such exclusive function named `listdir` defined in the module. In the code, from my limited understanding, the function is taken from `globals()` and put into a `support_fd` set. How this method is being called I do not understand.

I think the main problem I have is how that module is designed and I was not able to find any resources online to explain in simpler terms hence I am asking here for pointers.

EDIT: For those who are asking, I tried the following code in onlinegdb

```
import os

if "listdir" in os.__all__:
    print("Yes")
print(os.listdir())
```

The result is only `main.py`, it should also print `Yes`, maybe the platform `onlinegdb` is the problem but it clearly shows the output of `listdir` as `main.py`.

Comment: many of the builtin libs are written in C for speed

Comment: Adding to the previous comment: If you check `os.py` source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/os.py line `52` (`if 'posix' in _names:`) they check the operating system and import the necessary libraries depending on your OS.

Comment: Are you sure `print("listdir" in os.__all__)` doesn't return `True`? I think `os.listdir` is implemented [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/posixmodule.c) (lines 4006-4253).

Comment: @Timus I have added clarifications.

Comment: @AaryanBHAGAT Thanks, now I understand! The thing is: GDB-online's Python 3 is version 3.4.3. A lot has changed since then. Also, `__all__` might not be the best tool to look for available functions, because it's ment for import control (e.g. see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package)). If you try the following in GDB-online: `from os import *; listdir()` you'll get an error. That's because `listdir` is not in `os.__all__`. When you do `import os` and look at `dir(os)`, then you'll find it.

Comment: @Timus so what you mean is that if the method or attribute in not contained in `__all__` then upon doing `from os import *` it will not be imported, meaning a symbol for it will not be created but we can still use it `os.<module>`.

How does that relate with the old version of gdb?

And yes `dir(os)` did gave me the result.

Comment: @AaryanBHAGAT Regarding the first part: Yes. Regarding the relation to the old version: The behaviour has changed in the meantime, not sure exactly when. In more current versions `'listdir' in os.__all__` yields `True` (that's why I asked). See for example [here](https://ideone.com/3MdDcN) for 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having discussion in the comments I see now that this is more of a online python version problem and not an issue with python or the module itself.